# C# Equivalent of this C hash function

Tags: c#, c

I came across this C code which is a hashing algorithm to produce same hash for similar strings:

```c
unsigned long kaz_hash(const char *str)
{
    static unsigned long randbox[] = {
        0x49848f1bU, 0xe6255dbaU, 0x36da5bdcU, 0x47bf94e9U,
        0x8cbcce22U, 0x559fc06aU, 0xd268f536U, 0xe10af79aU,
        0xc1af4d69U, 0x1d2917b5U, 0xec4c304dU, 0x9ee5016cU,
        0x69232f74U, 0xfead7bb3U, 0xe9089ab6U, 0xf012f6aeU,
    };

    long acc = 0;

    while (*str) {
        acc ^= randbox[(*str + acc) & 0xf];
        acc = (acc << 1) | (acc >> 31);
        acc &= 0xffffffffU;
        acc ^= randbox[((*str++ >> 4) + acc) & 0xf];
        acc = (acc << 2) | (acc >> 30);
        acc &= 0xffffffffU;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

I am trying to use this in C#, this is what I came up with:

```cs
public static ulong kaz_hash(string str) {
  ulong[] randbox = {
    0x49848f1bU, 0xe6255dbaU, 0x36da5bdcU, 0x47bf94e9U,
    0x8cbcce22U, 0x559fc06aU, 0xd268f536U, 0xe10af79aU,
    0xc1af4d69U, 0x1d2917b5U, 0xec4c304dU, 0x9ee5016cU,
    0x69232f74U, 0xfead7bb3U, 0xe9089ab6U, 0xf012f6aeU,
  };

  long acc = 0;

  foreach (long c in str) {
    acc ^= (long)randbox[(c + acc) & 0xf];
    acc = (acc << 1) | (acc >> 31);
    acc &= 0xffffffffU;
    acc ^= (long)randbox[((c >> 4) + acc) & 0xf];
    acc = (acc << 2) | (acc >> 30);
    acc &= 0xffffffffU;
  }
  return (ulong)acc;
}
```

However, there is something wrong. The 2 functions aren't producing the same results.

**Edit**

Thanks to all comments and help. I was finally able to make this work. Below is the working version:

```cs
public static uint kaz_hash(string str) {
  uint[] randbox = {
    0x49848f1bU, 0xe6255dbaU, 0x36da5bdcU, 0x47bf94e9U,
    0x8cbcce22U, 0x559fc06aU, 0xd268f536U, 0xe10af79aU,
    0xc1af4d69U, 0x1d2917b5U, 0xec4c304dU, 0x9ee5016cU,
    0x69232f74U, 0xfead7bb3U, 0xe9089ab6U, 0xf012f6aeU,
  };

  int acc = 0;

  unchecked {
    foreach (int c in str) {
      acc ^= (int)randbox[(c + acc) & 0xf];
      acc = (acc << 1) | (acc >> 31);
      acc &= (int)0xffffffffU;
      acc ^= (int)randbox[((c >> 4) + acc) & 0xf];
      acc = (acc << 2) | (acc >> 30);
      acc &= (int)0xffffffffU;
    }
  }
  return (UInt32)acc;
}
```

Comment: c long is 32 bits so the c# code should use an int

Comment: `unsigned long` in C is (typically) 32-bits, `ulong` in c# is 64.

Comment: Also a `char` in c does not translate to a `char` in c#, and a `char*` in c is not equivalent to a `string` in c#.

Comment: @Alex - but those are not really problems here. The translation by the Op is largely OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman true, if the input is generated in managed land, not necessarily if it is used to compare c and c# outputs for the "same string".

Comment: I replaced `unsigned long` with `uint` and `long` with `int` but something is still broken. Also when changing `long acc = 0;` to `int acc = 0;` C# doesn't compile and complains on `acc &= 0xffffffffU;` casting doesn't work too. I can see the results differ on this line: `acc = (acc << 1) | (acc >> 31);` but I am not sure why.

Comment: Is your C++ code correct? I did a test with it and these are my results: "abc" -> -1; "abcd" -> -2, "abcde" -> -2. Looks like it is not a good hashing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below with "abc", "abcd", and "abcde" and the C# code returns the same value as for the C++ code:

```
    public static int kaz_hash(string str)
        {
            UInt32[] randbox = {
            0x49848f1bU, 0xe6255dbaU, 0x36da5bdcU, 0x47bf94e9U,
            0x8cbcce22U, 0x559fc06aU, 0xd268f536U, 0xe10af79aU,
            0xc1af4d69U, 0x1d2917b5U, 0xec4c304dU, 0x9ee5016cU,
            0x69232f74U, 0xfead7bb3U, 0xe9089ab6U, 0xf012f6aeU,
            };

            int acc = 0;

            foreach (UInt32 c in str)
            {                    
                acc ^= (int)randbox[(c + acc) & 0xf];                    
                acc = (acc << 1) | (acc >> 31);
                acc &= -1;
                acc ^= (int)randbox[((c >> 4) + acc) & 0xf];
                acc = (acc << 2) | (acc >> 30);
                acc &= -1;
            }
            return acc;
        }
```